# Nested classes for a multiple-phase state

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I would like to use nested classes for a "developing state":

```
public class WebSvcClient : IDisposable
{
    //
    // 10 private fields required by all methods
    ...

    public Profile Profile { get; private set; }
    public void Authenticate()
    {
        this.Profile = new Profile();
    }
    public class Profile
    {
        // public methods that do require authentication
        ...
    }

    // public methods that don't require authentication
    ...
}
```

I can see several benefits:

- Encapsulation, `Profile` makes sense only in the context of `WebSvcClient`
- Single `IDisposable` unit
- Lack of need for 3rd class just to pass the private fields to `Profile`
- No pollution of namespace

But is it considered good practice?

Comment: So if the `Profile` class is consider public in the scope of `WebSvcClient` how can `WebSvcClient` make it public to the rest of the application? So actually `Profile` is in fact public to the rest of the application. So it should be in its own file!

Comment: @Callum That can be achieved using partial classes as well.

Comment: Your code is not clear. Do you intend to pass an instance of WebSvcClient  to each Profile ?

Comment: @Henk There is only one instance of `Profile` (the `Profile` property). Yes, I intend to pass an instance of `WebSvcClient` to the nested class as I need its private fields accessible there.

Comment: The code (around new Profile()) should reflect that, it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using interfaces that represent state, and methods that can transition from one state to another:

```
public interface INew {
    // transition to initialized state
    IInitialized Init();
}
```

and

```
public interface IInitialized {
    // connect to get a connected object
    IConnected Connect(string connection);
}
```

and

```
public interface IConnected {
    // disconnect reverts back in state
    IInitialized Disconnect();

    // methods only available when connected
    bool GetValue(string name);
    void SetValue(string name, bool value);
}
```

Etc..

You can implement these interfaces on a common class, or use a different class for every state. You will need some kind of factory to create the initial instance.

This works well when you are in full control of the actual state (no unexpected disconnect etc..).

This way you are telling the users of your API what they need to do, in what order, to get access to the desired methods. You can use 'fluent' code to use this:

```
var newMachine = Factory.NewMachine();
var connected = newMachine
    .Init()
    .Connect(connectionString);

connected.GetValue("test");
...

connected.Disconnect();
```

Comment: What is this pattern called?

Comment: I think it would be overkill to give this pattern a name. It has some drawbacks that make it impractical. For example; there is nothing preventing from calling `connected.GetValue()` after you called Disconnect() but kept a reference to the `connected` interface. This pattern works great when you're 'zooming in' to the data (you;re forced to call `Connect()` first), but it does not protect you when 'zooming out'.

Answer (score 1):

There are no benefits:

- Encapsulation is about modifiers. Your nested class and its methods are public. If you don't reach to nested class from outside, you can use private class for pollution.
- IDisposable unit is related to the implementer class only. The nested class won't be affected.
- Pollution doesn't come from namespaces, it comes from bad designs, and bad naming practices. Keep in mind that you are not the only developer. The next developers must understand your code, so they should see the code easily by exploring file names. Or they have to check all code file by file.

Comment: 1. I do need to reach the public methods of the nested class from outside. 2. The nested class needs to use the private fields of parent and some of those are disposable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any gain here.

> - Encapsulation, Profile makes sense only in the context of WebSvcClient

But using private fields in another class, even when it's nested, breaks encapsulation.

> - Single IDisposable unit

It causes more problems then it solves here. What if other code keeps a Profile around after the Service was disposed?

> - Lack of need for 3rd class just to pass the private fields to Profile

Ok, maybe. That class would have been messy anyway.

> - No pollution of namespace

That's not really an issue anyway.

---

As an alternative, use two interfaces, or at least one for the Profile part. Implement the relevant members explicit so that they are only available through an  `IProfile` reference.
This can be circumvented with casting, but if that's a problem you should speak with your team. It would matter for a library, but it shouldn't for an Application.